# how to feed a deparse parse sequence with text instead of expression ? denominator entry of ipwpoint function

Tags: r, parsing, regression

I am facing a problem when using `ipwpoint` function from `ipw` package.
Here is a working example with the function `ipwpoint`:

```
library(ipw)
df <- data.frame(ttt = sample(0:1,500,replace = T),
                 cofounder1 = rnorm(500),
                 cofounder2 = rnorm(500))

ipwt <- ipwpoint(
  exposure = ttt ,
  family = "binomial",
  link = "logit",
  numerator = ~ 1,
  denominator = ~cofounder1 + cofounder2 ,
  data = df
)
```

Suppose now that I want to define the same regression, but with the denominator coming from a vector of variable names

```
vars <- c("cofounder1","cofounder2")
```

I thought I could use a formula:

```
formula <- as.formula(paste0("~",paste0(vars,collapse = "+")))
ipwt <- ipwpoint(
  exposure = ttt ,
  family = "binomial",
  link = "logit",
  numerator = ~ 1,
  denominator = formula,
  data = df
)
```

But this does not work:

> Error in eval(parse(text = paste(deparse(tempcall$exposure, width.cutoff = 500),  :
> object 'tttformula' not found

because what the function does is that is deparse an expression to then paste it with the `exposure`, and parse it again and evaluate it, see https://github.com/cran/ipw/blob/master/R/ipwpoint.R#L87. So it pastes "formula" instead of the actual formula.

Using text does not work either:

```
ipwt <- ipwpoint(
  exposure = ttt ,
  family = "binomial",
  link = "logit",
  numerator = ~ 1,
  denominator = paste0("~",paste0(vars,collapse = "+")),
  data = df
)
```

How can I do to define my regression from the `c("cofounder1","cofounder2")` vector ?

Comment: You can do the same with the `WeightIt` package, which doesn't have this peculiarity.

Comment: thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about parsing the whole function call as string?:

```
function_call<-paste0("ipwt <- ipwpoint(
  exposure = ttt ,
  family = \"binomial\",
  link = \"logit\",
  numerator = ~ 1,
  denominator = ~",vars[1]," + ",vars[2]," ,
  data = df
)")

eval(parse(text = function_call))
```